# Metaphor for activity like writing a text with much devotion and stressfully

Tags: metaphors

I am looking for an interesting metaphor (well adapted if possible) to describe activities similar to writing an article in stressful conditions, but with much devotion. Such writing could then result in a text that is like "hard boiled", but that's just an approximate, incorrect description, as the idiom refers to a person. I am thinking about "frying text". The metaphor could be used in following example situation: someone who worked for multiple hours late at night on an article meets a colleague, and he asks him:

- So did you fry a good text?
- Yeah I fried a piece, really good for the front page.

Just to make the situation complete, the text could be about a recent event that required immediate reaction from a newspaper, e.g. a train catastrophe or other serious event, and a devoted employee decided to quickly "fry" an article.

Comment: Hard-boiled has literary connotations already. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardboiled Do you mean metaphor? Pressure cook might work.

Comment: Or microwave...

Comment: ["scribed an account"](https://www.google.com/search?q=scribed+an+acount&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22scribed+an+account%22) sounds pretty official to me. ~2k hits, with quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for something like **[pound out](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pound+out)**, an idiomatic phrase meaning "to produce something at great speed, requiring great effort in pressing keys".  It is often used in the context of creating written works quickly (on a keyboard) through hard work:

> The aspiring journalist was hired after he proved he could pound out three full articles on any breaking news story in under two hours.

The phrase doesn't necessarily imply that the conditions are stressful, though that is frequently the case, as the great speed is usually the result of an implied incipient deadline.

Comment: That's a great expression. I to some extent wanted expression more general (was about to settle also on strictly article writing because of disbelief that such expression exist), but the "pount out" has such quality that I might accept the answer regardless of the narrow meaning (for which I also myself asked in the title).